# How to get multiple points for next evaluations when performing Bayesian optimization using Dragonfly

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, bayesian

I am using Bayesian optimization to optimize chemical reactions (in silico). I would like to use the parallelization option provided in Dragonfly (mentioned in their journal) to get multiple inputs for the evaluation.  However, in their documentation, it is not explicitly explained.

I use the following code for initializing my current problem.

```
`options = Namespace(
    init_capital = 45, 
     )    

# domain for optimization
  domain_vars = [
    {'type': 'float', 'min': 0.5, 'max': 2, 'dim': 1},
    {'type': 'float', 'min': 30, 'max': 120, 'dim': 1},
    {'type': 'float', 'min': 0.1, 'max': 0.5, 'dim': 1},
    {'type': 'float', 'min': 1, 'max': 5, 'dim': 1},
    {'type': 'discrete', 'items': discrete_values_as_ints_1},
    {'type': 'discrete', 'items': discrete_values_as_ints_2}  # This will be updated
  ]

config_params = {'domain': domain_vars}
config = load_config(config_params)


options.progress_load_from = 'input_dragonfly.p'


Surrogate_objectives= (calling_surrogate, 2)

opt_pt,opt_val,history = multiobjective_maximise_functions(Surrogate_objectives,config.domain, n_opt,
                                    config=config,options=options)`
```